# QuickSight - Count of active events over time

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

I have a event dataset in QuickSight, where each record has two date fields: startDate and endDate. An event is considered active at time T if T is between startDate and endDate. I want to build a visualization of active events over time as a line chart. However, I am struggling to understand how that can be done in AWS QuickSight. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, So Basically you need an aggregated numbers of active events on the time graph ?

Comment: @nagesh Yes. I want to see a graph of count of active events over time.

Comment: Can you please provide some dummy data for more understanding and plotting ?
I am assuming you need to plot general date on X axis and aggregation based on active event definition ( An event is considered active at time T if T is between startDate and endDate )

Comment: I ran into the same problem. To make it more clear, I have updated the post with a sample dataset.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a calculated field "Active" as follows:

```
ifelse(
  dateDiff(T,startDate)>=0 and dateDiff(endDate,T)>=0,
  1,
  0
)
```

Now, you can add a filter on that field and plot a line graph with T on x-axis and count or sum(Active) on y-axis and drill down as per your requirement.
Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no field T in this case.