# AWS Quicksight Count active events over time

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a dataset that consists of 3 values :

**UserID**, **ConnectionTime**, **DisconnectionTime**

I would like to build a line graph with Time as X Axis and count of users as Y axis

I cannot use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066063/quicksight-count-of-active-events-over-time?answertab=active#tab-top) because I don't have a Time "T" or Date column

Comment: I have the same issue. Commenting to see if you were able to get an answer.

Comment: I do not have any update, sorry